# creating query from data recived from javascript via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following javascript:

```
function update_number_of_adds_found(field_dropdown, selected_value) {
    selected_value="";
    for(i=0; i<document.submitadd.elements.length; i++){
        if(document.submitadd.elements[i].value !='' && document.submitadd.elements[i].value != 'Αναζήτηση' && document.submitadd.elements[i].checked !=''){
            selected_value += (document.submitadd.elements[i].name +'-' + document.submitadd.elements[i].value +' ');
        }
    }
    var result5 = $.ajax({
        'url': '<?php echo site_url('search/findNumberOfAdds'); ?>/' + selected_value,
        'async': false
    }).responseText;

    $('#totalNumOfAdds').empty();
    $("#totalNumOfAdds").append(result5);
}
```

This script send the data in the following format:

```
addtypeid-1%20isnew-1%20geographicareaid-3
```

I am a bit restriced in which symbols i can use, because I am using codeigniter, and if I use & for example i get message that i use dissalowed characters in my url.

My question is how can i transform this data in the format $key['fieldname'] = $value['fieldvalue'] so i can built my where clausule?

I was trying something with explode or replace, but without success so far. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: can you not serialize your form? and deserialize in PHP?

Comment: I need only the fields that are not empty, not all of them. Form is quite big. Also, I am not a javascript master actually. Code snippet would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following up on my comment above ... You can try something like this ... I haven't tested it but should give you ideas to how to go about ...

```
jQuery('.submit').click(function(){
    var str = $("#myForm").serialize();
    str += '&serialize=' + encodeURIComponent(str);
    str += '&action=myformsubmit';
    jQuery.ajax('phpscripturl.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: str,
        success: function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert('Sending...');
        }
    });
    return false;   
});
```

By serializing the form inputs with jQuery's serialize you create a string like:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5&postID=10
```

So you can fetch this serialized data as
$data = $_POST['serialize'];

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
   if($value == '') continue; //skip empty values as per your request

   //else save in db etc ...
}
```

Comment: I get now the following error in php: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: serialize</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/search.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 167</p>

Answer (score 0):

Build an JSON object then Stringify and post it in one variable. Then use json_decode($_POST['key']) to create a PHP object and can access the values easily.

In JS

```
  var ValueToSend = new Object();
  ValueToSend.field1 = value1;
  var postString = JSON.stringify(ValueToSend)
```

In PHP

```
  $Object = decode_json($_POST['key']);
```